# SharpDX DirectInput Force feedback actuators are missing

Tags: sharpdx, directinput, force-feedback

I am using a simple code to read input from a DirectInput device. I would like to add force feedback to the device, however when I run this test, I cannot find any ForceFeedbackActuator, however my device supports rumble effects.

```
public void Test(Joystick joystick)
{
    joystick.SetCooperativeLevel(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle, CooperativeLevel.Background | CooperativeLevel.Exclusive);
    joystick.Properties.AxisMode = DeviceAxisMode.Absolute;
    joystick.Properties.AutoCenter = false;
    joystick.Acquire();

    foreach (var deviceObjectInstance in joystick.GetObjects())
    {
        if (deviceObjectInstance.ObjectId.Flags.HasFlag(DeviceObjectTypeFlags.ForceFeedbackActuator))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the Microsoft specification but found nothing so far.

However my driver is null as well:

```
deviceInstance.ForceFeedbackDriverGuid
```

But this can be set from registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick\OEM` adding a new `CLSID` value for the current device.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How's the enumeration under XInput?  Is this a feature for your controller that is only supported on the latter toolkit?  Looks like everything else you are doing should is fine.

Comment: I am using a Logitech F510, which can be used as XInput or DirectInput device. I cannot make this code work in either mode.

Comment: Hmmm then in that case there are a couple and overly lengthy options.  1 would be to build a test harness in c++ to test that sharpdx is not supporting correctly your controller.  If so then a ticket can be raised on the git hub issues.   If not then you know it maybe something deeper with directx or driver.   I assume you have some current directx 11 which works anyway which may point to a sharpdx issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLSID i have used is invalid. I installed the official software of the device, and actuators are available now.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer :) And when you're done, please flag this comment as no longer needed, I'll remove it.

Comment: I do not know how to mark it no longer needed. It is the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey this is an old post I know. But there has been frustrating little support and documentation on this. I'm having a similar issue. I know my device has force feedback capabilities but none of the joystick objects are flagged as such and driver GUI shows as a bunch of 0's when printed.

I have little knowledge of what many of these things even mean. What is a CLSID?